# Strange Behavior After Implementing Text-Gap In C++

Tags: c++

I have attempted to implement a text-gap text-editor, and at first glance everything seems to work. But, at seemingly random points, garbage data will enter the mix. I've included the code with all GUI and graphical shennanigans removed, just the text gap class and its buddies implemented in a simple main, with an attached log of the console output when run with g++ main.cpp -o main.

P.S. Text gap means dividing in-memory text into at least two data structures, but presenting them to the user as an uninterrupted stream, allowing easy insertion/deletion/cursor semantics. Essentiall stringA+stringB=whatusersees. Thus an insertion is a simple push-back on the first-half, and a delete key is a pop-front on the second half. Moving the cursor in either direction means simply popping from one direction and pushing in the other.

PPS. In my multiple runs the garbage data does not show when input is pushed in, either as a character or as the final string. Also, the error occurs seemingly randomly, sometimes after only a few characters, sometimes after a lot.

PPPS. I can can rid of it by essentially using a string-n-copy function to clean the whole set of values, but that won't work unless I run it during the first half of concatTextBlockRange. And its relatively expensive, when all I should be doing is accessing a dereferenced iterator, not accessing a dereferenced iterator and then counting off parts of it.

PPPPS. There is no garbage data before the first half of concatTextBlockRange, but it is present whenever the dataIter is pointing at a 'contaminated,' character position, which contains both the character (h or g or whatever) and also a bunch of unintelligible garbage data. The second half does not seem to generate this. The generation is not reliable, though it will occur if you keep entering keys.

CODE:

```
//test2.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct TextBlock{
    std::list<char> data;
    void assign( std::string inStr ) {
        std::string::iterator myIter = inStr.begin();
        std::string::iterator end = inStr.end();
        while( myIter != end ) {
            data.push_back( (*myIter) );
            ++myIter;
        }
    }
    char pop_front(  ) {
        if( data.empty() == true ) { std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl; return '#'; }
        char toret = data.front();
        data.pop_front();
        return toret;
    }
    char pop_back(  ) {
        if( data.empty() == true ) { std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl; return '?'; }
        char toret = data.back();
        data.pop_back();
        return toret;
    }
    void push_front( char inChar ) { data.push_front( inChar ); }
    void push_back( char inChar ) { data.push_back( inChar ); }
    void backspace_key(  ) { data.pop_back(); }
    void delete_key(  ) { data.pop_front(); }
    int size(  ) { return data.size(); }
    bool empty(  ) { return data.empty(); }
    void PrintString(  ) {
        std::cout << ".:::PRINTING:::." << std::endl;
        std::list<char>::iterator myIter = data.begin();
        std::list<char>::iterator end = data.end();
        while( myIter != end ) {
            std::cout << (*myIter);
            ++myIter;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

std::string concatTextBlockRange( const TextBlock * const in1, const TextBlock * const in2, int backrange, int frontrange ) {
    std::string toret;

    std::list<char>::const_iterator dataIter1 = in1->data.end();
    for( int i=0; i<backrange; i++ ) { --dataIter1; }
    for( int i=0; i<backrange; i++ ) {
        toret.append( &(*dataIter1) );
        ++dataIter1;
    }

    std::list<char>::const_iterator dataIter2 = in2->data.begin();
    for( int i=0; i<frontrange; i++ ) {
        toret.append( &(*dataIter2) );
        ++dataIter2;
    }
    return toret;
}

class Text{
public:
    Text( std::string inFirst, std::string inSecond ) {
        First.assign(inFirst);
        Second.assign(inSecond);
    }
    void incGap(  ) {
        if( Second.empty() == false ) { First.push_back( Second.pop_front() ); }
    }
    void decGap(  ) {
        if( First.empty() == false ) { Second.push_front( First.pop_back() ); }
    }
    void incGap( int reps ) {
        for( int i=0; i<reps; i++ ) { First.push_back( Second.pop_front() ); }
    }
        void decGap( int reps ) {
            for( int i=0; i<reps; i++ ) { Second.push_front( First.pop_back() );                 }
    }
    void insert( char inKey ) {
        First.push_back( inKey );
    }
    void delete_key(  ) {
        Second.delete_key();
    }
    void backspace_key(  ) {
    First.backspace_key();
    }
    void space_key(  ) {
        insert(' ');
    }
    std::string retString( int backrange, int frontrange ) {
        if( frontrange >= Second.size() ) { frontrange = Second.size(); }
        if( backrange >= First.size() ) { backrange = First.size(); }
        return concatTextBlockRange( &First, &Second, backrange, frontrange );
    }
private:
    TextBlock First, Second;
};


int main(){
    Text myText( "The cat " , " because "  );
    char in;
    bool tripped;
    while( in != '`' ) {
        std::cout << myText.retString(1000,1000) << std::endl;
        tripped = false;
        std::cin >> in;
        if( in == ']' ) { myText.incGap(); tripped = true; }
        if( in == '[' ) { myText.decGap(); tripped = true; }
        if( in == '\\' ) { myText.backspace_key(); tripped = true; }
        if( in == '-' ) { myText.delete_key(); tripped = true; }
        if( in == '_' ) { myText.space_key(); tripped = true; }
        if( tripped == false ) { myText.insert( in ); }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
The cat  because 
qwer
The cat q because 
The cat qw because 
The cat qwe because 
The cat qwer because 
qwerttyyu
The cat qwerq because 
The cat qwerqw because 
The cat qwerqwe because 
The cat qwerqwer because 
The cat qwerqwert because 
The cat qwerqwertt because 
The cat qwerqwertty because 
The cat qwerqwerttyy because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyu because 
yuiop
The cat qwerqwerttyyuy because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyu because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyui because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuio because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiop because 
sdfghj
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiops because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsd because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdf because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfg because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfgh because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghj because 
ertasfj
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghje because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjer because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjert because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjerta because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertas because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasf because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfj because 
dsrtjgf
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjd because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjds because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsr because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrt because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtj because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjg because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgf because 
dftjdgh
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfd because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdf because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdft because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftj because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjd because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdg because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdgh because 
sfgkjsdfgj
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghs because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsf because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfg because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk��� because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk���j���fghj1 because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk���j���fghj1s���` because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk���j���fghj1s���`d��� because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk���j���fghj1s���`d���f���` because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk���j���fghj1s���`d���f���`g��� because 
The cat qwerqwerttyyuyuiopsdfghjertasfjdsrtjgfdftjdghsfgk���j���fghj1s���`d���f���`g���j���` because
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a wrong overload of `string::append`, namely `append(const char *)`.  It expects as an argument a `NUL`-terminated, so-called "C" string which is incompatible with what returned from `std::list<char>::const_iterator`.

The shortest way to fix this bug is to call another overload `append(size_t, char)` by writing `toret.append(1, *dataiter1)` etc.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/

I could spot this bug relatively easily by running your sample program under the Valgrind memory debugger:

- http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

---

Just FYI, have you checked `__gnu_cxx::rope` with which I think you may replace your own implementation of gap buffer?

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00066.html

Comment: Absolutely right. The correct overload fixed it. Thank you very much, this was challenging me for a while.